# Generated AAR file not contain its dependency modules

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I am trying to generate AAR file for some modules which already has some other modules as its dependency.But the generated AAR file doesn't contain those dependency modules.
Ex: If i have project1 which has dependecies pro2 and pro3,but pro1 AAR file neither contains pro2 nor pro3.
compile project(':pro2')
compile project(':pro3')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not intended that `aar` files contain their own dependencies. Instead, information about dependencies should be managed by a dependency management system like Maven